# How to show the Google translated text in a Swing component?

Tags: java, swing, unicode, fonts

I am translating some English word to another language using google translator. I want to show the translated text in a Java Swing component. When I try to set the text of the component using the 'setText()' method, it is showing some box symbols instead of the translated text. May be because of encoding/decoding issue of Unicode format. How can I show the translated text successfully in a Swing component?

Comment: *"javax swing componeny"* Be more specific. What component? Having the ability to display characters usually depends on the `Font`. Use `Font.canDisplayUpTo(..)` to check.

Comment: suppose JTextarea

Comment: If you SYSO the translated text, what do you get?

Comment: some question mark symbols like '????'

Comment: Write some unit tests around the google translate API you're using. The reason you'd do this is to verify that the API is doing what you want, these are called **Learning Tests** and are covered in the book, Clean Code (you can find PDFs online but I feel immoral posting links). Once you've got the translation part working, setting the text will be a breeze.

Comment: You may also have to enable localization for the target language on your specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

This should be all about it:

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8");
```